# How to drag an image to move it smoothly on screen, with ActionScript?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, drag

I was thinking this is a simple task, but I'm wrong.

I used a sprite to display an image, and when user drag it(MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_MOVE), I got the position in `MOUSE_MOVE` and calculated the offsets:

```
 var current: Point = new Point(event.localX, event.localY);
 sprite.x = current.x - start.x;
 sprite.y = current.y - start.y;
```

It works but not smooth. Is there a better solution?

---

**UPDATE**

After a day of debugging, I finally found the reason.

Bigger **fps** can make it smoother, but it's not the key of this question.

The key is I should use `stage` to listen `MOUSE_MOVE`, not the image itself. And when getting the mouse position, I should use `event.stageX/Y`(or `stage.mouseX/Y`), not `event.localX/Y`. The `event.localX/Y` from the moving image, is neither stable nor smooth, that causes my problem.

Following is my working code, enjoy it :)

```
package {
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class DragIssue extends Sprite {

        private static const URL: String = "assets/m1.jpg";

        private var self: DragIssue;

        private var sprite: Sprite;

        private var startPoint: Point;

        private var offsetX: Number = 0;
        private var offsetY: Number = 0;

        public function DragIssue() {
            self = this;
            init();
            loadImage();
        }

        protected function init(): void {
            if (stage == null) {
                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, on_addedToStage);
            } else {
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
            }

            function on_addedToStage(event: Event): void {
                self.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, on_addedToStage);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
            }
        }

        public function loadImage(): void {
            var loader: Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
            loader.load(new URLRequest(URL));

            function imageLoaded(event: Event): void {
                var bitmap: Bitmap = event.target.content as Bitmap;

                self.sprite = new Sprite();
                sprite.addChild(bitmap);

                self.addChild(sprite);

                sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
                sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
            }
        }

        private function onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
            if (startPoint) {
                sprite.x = offsetX + event.stageX - startPoint.x;
                sprite.y = offsetY + event.stageY - startPoint.y;
            }
        }

        private function onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent): void {
            startPoint = null;
            offsetX = sprite.x;
            offsetY = sprite.y;
        }

        private function onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void {
            startPoint = new Point(event.stageX, event.stageY);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this. It's just a simple black square, but it looks fine until you *really* start dragging it around. As was mentioned, setting the framerate to something higher is ideal.  In this case, I decided to up the framerate to 60fps in the MOUSE_DOWN and drop it back to 24 in MOUSE_UP for memory reasons. You can obviously change that how you please.

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;


var startX:Number;
var startY:Number;
var shape:Sprite = new Sprite();
shape.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
shape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
shape.graphics.endFill();
this.addChild(shape);

shape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,this.mouseDown);

function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
    stage.frameRate = 60;
    startX = stage.mouseX - shape.x;
    startY = stage.mouseY - shape.y;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,this.mouseMove);
    shape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,this.mouseUp);
}

function mouseMove(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
    shape.x = stage.mouseX - startX;
    shape.y = stage.mouseY - startY;
}

function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
    shape.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,this.mouseUp);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,this.mouseMove);
    stage.frameRate = 24;
}
```

Make sure you are removing the MOUSE_MOVE event on MOUSE_UP. That is key. Otherwise, you re-add the event on every MOUSE_DOWN and end up running the same code repeatedly, simultaneously. Sorry my syntax isn't 100% proper; I threw this together really quick in CS5.5 rather than doing it in Flash Builder.

Comment: I found the real reason is that I should use `event.stageX/Y` or `stage.mouseX/Y` like you. I was using `event.localX` on a sprite, which is not stable when moving.

Comment: No, it's completely stable. Problem is that localX/Y is relative to the 0,0 point of the target, not the stage. And everything was unsmooth because you were calculating the movements against a constantly moving point. Whenever you are moving something, always do it in relation to the stage rather than an object on the stage. If you have a window or something that the obj must move within, account for that with conditionals rather than another object. In the end, it is far more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a high framerate to have smooth movement. The optimal framerate is 60fps because it is the default for most LCD monitors.

I don't have the code under my hand so I put the code here (not tested)

```
yourClip.addeventListenner(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrag);

function startDrag(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
    // record positon of the mouse relative to the clip
    deltaX=stage.mouseX-yourClip.x;
    deltaY=stage.mouseY-yourClip.y;
    // attach on mouse move event
    yourClip.addeventListenner(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateDrag);
    // attach stop event (on Stage)
    Stage.addeventListenner(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrag);
    }
function updateDrag(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
    yourClip.x=stage.mouseX-deltaX
    yourClip.y=stage.mouseY-deltaY
}

function stopDrag(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
   yourClip.removeEventListenner(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateDrag);
   stage.removeEventListenner(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrag);
}
```

Comment: Please see my screencast: http://www.screenr.com/wb68 , it's far away from smooth, because it jumps all the time. I think there must be something wrong in my code

Comment: I just found I should use `startDrag()` and `stopDrag()`.

Comment: This answer just emulates the startDrag() method of the `Sprite` class. Why not just use that? or are you wanting to drag a display object that doesn't inherit from `Sprite`? - that would seem unlikely as the example uses the name sprite as the object to be dragged

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices Because you can customize the different events. For example changing the aspect of the clip while dragging. I like adding a shadow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for smooth dragging experience, here is a method you could use:  (let's say the thing you're dragging is called 'dragee' and this code is in the scope of dragee's parent)

```
function startDragging():void {
    dragee.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,dragUpdate);
}

function stopDragging():void {
    dragee.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,dragUpdate);
}

var decay:Number = .25; //1 is no decay, .1 would be cazy slow

function dragUpdate(e:Event):void {
    dragee.x += decay * (mouseX - dragee.x);
    dragee.y += decay * (mouseY - dragee.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `event.updateAfterEvent()` in your drag handler. The function tells Flash to redraw the stage immediately instead of waiting til the next frame.