# How drag a Sprite smoothly on-screen in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

First of all, my question is basically the same as this one:

[How to drag an image to move it smoothly on screen, with ActionScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321780/how-to-drag-an-image-to-move-it-smoothly-on-screen-with-actionscript)

I want my dragged Sprites to keep up with the mouse on-screen, smoothly, without lagging behind.

And I notice that in the old ActionScript 3 Cookbook from way-back-when that they used a similar solution for their DraggableSprite as was used in the above link. Namely, use the stage instance to listen for the MouseMove event and then read from the event.stageX and stageY properties.

I've done that.

But my Sprite still doesn't stay locked with the mouse cursor. It lags behind. I feel like I must be missing something. However, if the solution posted above (ie listen for stage's MouseMove and use event.stageX/Y) is still current and the problem I'm describing should not be occurring, please also let me know. Even though it's not supposed to work, I've tried event.updateAfterEvent() and it also doesn't seem to have any positive effect.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a simple example of how I've written the handlers. It should work as-is if pasted into a new project.

I should also add that I'm compiling this as a desktop application using Adobe AIR. Would the run time be a factor???

```
package {
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;

  [SWF(width="1280", height="720", frameRate="30")]
  public class test_drag extends Sprite {

    private var testDragSprite:TestDragSprite;

    public function test_drag() {
      super();

      graphics.clear();
      graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
      graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 1280, 720);
      graphics.endFill();

      testDragSprite = new TestDragSprite();
      addChild(testDragSprite);

      testDragSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, testDragSprite_mouseHandler);
      testDragSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, testDragSprite_mouseHandler);
    }

    private function testDragSprite_mouseHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
      switch (e.type) {
        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN: {
          stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
          break;
        }
        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP: {
          stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    private function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
      //-20 to keep the sprite centered on the mouse
      testDragSprite.x = e.stageX - 20;
      testDragSprite.y = e.stageY - 20;
      //e.updateAfterEvent(); //strange effect, but doesn't solve the problem.
    }
  }
}
import flash.display.Sprite;
internal class TestDragSprite extends Sprite {
  public function TestDragSprite() {
    super();
    graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xDDDDDD);
    graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 40, 40, 12);
    graphics.endFill();
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always going to be a little lag, but:

*The first two suggestions will make the most noticeable change to your code/performance.*

- Enable hardware graphics acceleration; edit your AIR application
  descriptor file (xml) and set renderMode to Direct (or GPU). Consult
  the Adobe Air help for details.

  ```
  <!-- The render mode for the app (either auto, cpu, gpu, or direct). Optional. Default auto -->
  <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
  ```
- Use startDrag and endDrag to bypass your manual assignments in your mouseMoveHandler.

Replace :

```
testDragSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, testDragSprite_mouseHandler);
testDragSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, testDragSprite_mouseHandler);
```

With :

```
testDragSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
testDragSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
```

Add the new handlers:

```
private function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
    testDragSprite.startDrag();
}
private function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
    testDragSprite.stopDrag();
}
```

- Increase your frame rate, but watch your CPU usage as your application/game becomes more complicated as you may need to lower it to allow your game logic enough time to complete between frames (otherwise you end up with what is called long frames, you can use the free Adobe Scout profiling tool to watch for these and lots of other things).
- Add a frame rate HUD to your display so you can monitor when your actual framerate is lower than the requested framerate (this is for debugging)
- If your game is 2d based, consider using the open-source [Starling framework](http://gamua.com/starling/) as all content is rendered directly by the GPU vs Flash's standard display list objects.

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented all those changes already and realized you're right! I also have a HUD FPS counter. Even at 100FPS framerate, on my machine it won't get above around 50-60 when dragging. Starling looks like a better way to go. One last thing I thought of is using an opaque bitmap as a drag proxy. It will help performance slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the member function startDrag.

Answer (score 0):

The Feathers UI library includes a drag-and-drop module. The answers above all use the 'old' display list which is not mobile-ready. If you want your code to work cross-platform you need a GPU framework (most popular is Starling on which Feathers is based, as well as most Adobe AIR games and Apps).